# Angular ngOptions prepending string: to value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to build a directive for Angular that puts a label and select with all the required classes.  My directive code looks like this:

```
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '=',
            model: '=',
            options: '='
        },
        template: "<div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>{{text}}</label><select class='form-control' ng-model='model' ng-options='option.env as option.name for option in options'></select></div>"
```

And I call it use this:

```
 <select-input text="'Environment'" options="environments" model="request.Environment"></select-input>
```

In my controller, environments is defined as such:

```
$scope.environments = [
        { name: 'PROD', env: 'prod' },
        { name: 'N', env: 'n0' },
        { name: 'N1', env:'n1' },
        { name: 'N0', env: 'n2' },
    ];
```

However, when Angular transforms the directive to HTML, it results in

```
    <select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="model" ng-options="option.env as option.name for option in options"><option label="PROD" value="string:prod">PROD</option>
<option label="N" value="string:n0">N</option>
<option label="N1" value="string:n1">N1</option>
<option label="N0" value="string:n2" selected="selected">N0</option>
</select>
```

I'm confused why the string: is there in value attribute..

Answer (score 3):

Use **track by 'property'**.

Like this:

```
<select ..... ng-options="option.env as option.name for option in options track by option.env"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to worry about what the `value` attribute is since it is used internally.

Keep in mind that `ng-options` can be configured to pass different types of values to the model ... string, object, array, number etc.

So inspecting the value you have it's clear that the `typeof` value you configured for would be string and the model would get assigned `"prod"` if selected.

Another thing to keep in mind is the reverse binding that you don't see when angular has to set an existing model value on the select during rendering

To be honest i've never seen this value protocol that you are pointing out. It looks helpful for debugging when you get tripped up on incorrect `ng-options` syntax. I am guessing that is a feature that has been added in more recent versions of angular ... but I could be wrong and it's only because I haven't had to dig into dom at option tag level for a while

Answer (score 0):

Based on charliefl's response, I changed the source of the options to an object

```
  $scope.environments = {
        prod: 'PROD',
        n0: 'N',
        n1: 'N1',
        n2: 'N2'
    };
```

And the modified the ng-options clause to `key as value for (key,value) in options`. According to the documentation, this is a select clause, and the value of the select and options will be the property name, which in this case, are prod, n0, etc, which correspond to the value of the model's Environment value.